# Why does this scrapy proxymiddleware make duplicated requests?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I want to add proxy to spider with proxymiddleware, but i don't know why it filtered duplicated request

Here is the code:

```
class TaylorSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Taylor'
    allowed_domains = ['tandfonline.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.tandfonline.com/action/cookieAbsent']

    def start_requests(self):  
        yield Request(self.start_urls[0], dont_filter=True, callback = self.parse_start_url) 

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        item = TaylorspiderItem()
        item['PageUrl'] = response.url      

        yield item

# middleware.py

class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        logger.info('pr........................')
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://58.16.86.239:8080'
        return request        


# setting.py

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'TaylorSpider.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

when `dont_filter=True`,it get stuck in infinite loop, the log is

```
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:56:21 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
```

however when `dont_filter=False`,the log is

```
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [TaylorSpider.middlewares] INFO: pr........................
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.tandfonline.com/action/cookieAbsent> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 5, 54, 25, 422000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 5, 54, 25, 414000)}
2017-07-19 13:54:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

So how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Downloader middlewares' `process_request`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request) should return `None` if they only patch the request and want the framework to continue its processing:

> process_request() should either: return None, return a Response
>   object, return a Request object, or raise IgnoreRequest.
>
> If it returns None, Scrapy will continue processing this request,
>   executing all other middlewares until, finally, the appropriate
>   downloader handler is called the request performed (and its response
>   downloaded).
>
> (...)
>
> **If it returns a Request object, Scrapy will stop calling
>   process_request methods and reschedule the returned request.** Once the
>   newly returned request is performed, the appropriate middleware chain
>   will be called on the downloaded response.

So you want to drop the `return request` at the end of your `process_request`.